# Assembly delay subroutine

Tags: animation, assembly, delay

I need some basic information about the delay routine in assembly.

I'm trying to create a small animation and I got the basic of the routine from my teacher, but I don't understand how to implement it. When I call the subroutine everything lags and won't draw the rest of my graphic.

My questions: do I have to specify the animation related code in the delay? If not then do I have to create a loop to write my animation code  in there? and why does this code make my entire program stop?

```
    PUSH    CX
    PUSH    DX

OUTER_LOOP:
    MOV     CX,200
    DEC     CX
    JE      FINISH


INNER_LOOP:
    MOV     DX,0FFFFH
    DEC     DX
    JE      OUTER_LOOP
    JMP     INNER_LOOP

FINISH:

    POP     DX
    POP     CX
```

Answer (score 2):

Both your loops are infinite loops, because you reset the loop count to max at every iteration, instead of once before the loop.

```
OUTER_LOOP:
    MOV     CX,200       ; move this to before OUTER_LOOP:
    DEC     CX
    JE      FINISH


INNER_LOOP:
    MOV     DX,0FFFFH     ; move this to before INNER_LOOP:
    DEC     DX
    JE      OUTER_LOOP
    JMP     INNER_LOOP
```

It's a delay loop, so being slow is the *goal*, but you could have written it more compactly:

```
    MOV     CX,200
    XOR     DX,DX  ; inner loop does 65536 iterations, not 65535
OUTER_LOOP:
INNER_LOOP:
    DEC     DX
    JNZ   INNER_LOOP
    DEC     CX
    JNZ   OUTER_LOOP
```

You could throw in a gratuitous `div` or something to slow things down more.